# Does anyone recognize this image file format

Tags: image, file-format

Yes I know about magic numbers, yes I know about: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html (awesome site).  I have binary files that are in some sort of image file format that I can't identify.  They all start with: 01 00 00 00 36 06 ae 00.  Does anyone know what format that would be?  It's NOT an EMF or WMF (at least not a valid one).

Thanks!

Comment: If nothing else matches, could be a camera RAW file, which are basically just the rgb triplets from the camera's sensors, with no processing/headers.

Comment: *Is* there an extension? Any `strings` in it?

Comment: There is no extension and no strings that I've found.  It could be raw I suppose!  Any good tools for probing raw images?  Should I just try renaming to every possible raw file format and attempt to load it in irfanview or some other program?

Answer (score 0):

Heres a couple things you can try:

- Using the file size, subtracting the common header (the first 8 bytes you noted), see if the remaining length is a multiple of a common resolution

  - Example: File size of 2359304, minus the 8 bytes for the header is 2359296.  Divide that by three, and we get 786432, which is 1024 * 768.  This could mean that it is a file containing rgb triplets for a 1024x768 image, plus the header.
- Try reading the file as an array of pixels.  Try 32-bit, 24-bit, 16-bit, 8-bit colors.  Then try to display them.  When you display them, the colors could be messed up, picture could be flipped, etc.  Just look to see if there is a recognizable image.